# issues of dynamically adding button in android

Tags: android, android-layout, button

issue of dynamically adding button,so how can i make button go to next row automatically

Like this :

The Output that I want :

[image: The Output that I wanna]

The Output I got :

[image: The Output I got]

Here is my code:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout);

Button btn = new Button(getContext());
btn.setText("Button1");
btn.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Button btn1 = new Button(getContext());
btn1.setText("Button2");
btn1.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Button btn2 = new Button(getContext());
btn2.setText("Button3");
btn2.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Button btn3 = new Button(getContext());
btn3.setText("Button4");
btn3.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Button btn4 = new Button(getContext());
btn4.setText("Button5");
btn4.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

ll.addView(btn);
ll.addView(btn1);
ll.addView(btn2);
ll.addView(btn3);
ll.addView(btn4);
```

In XML:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>
```

I am new in Android, Thank Guys :)

Comment: You have set the linear layout orientation to horizontal.Make it vertical in order to get buttons in the next row autimatically.

Comment: try gridview https://www.android-examples.com/add-items-to-gridview-dynamically-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

Use my newly designed [PredicateLayout](https://github.com/rajandev17/BookMyDrive/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ggktech/bookmydrive/PredicateLayout.java) for such purpose to automatically move the button to next line as in

**XML**

```
<PredicateLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Java**

```
 PredicateLayout ll = (PredicateLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout);

    Button btn = new Button(getContext());
    btn.setText("Button1");
    btn.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    Button btn1 = new Button(getContext());
    btn1.setText("Button2");
    btn1.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    Button btn2 = new Button(getContext());
    btn2.setText("Button3");
    btn2.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    Button btn3 = new Button(getContext());
    btn3.setText("Button4");
    btn3.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    Button btn4 = new Button(getContext());
    btn4.setText("Button5");
    btn4.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ll.addView(btn);
    ll.addView(btn1);
    ll.addView(btn2);
    ll.addView(btn3);
    ll.addView(btn4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly set the LinearLayout Orientation to vertical

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need few button in each row

Comment: Let me make it how you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutSubParent = new LinearLayout(AddNewContactActivity.this);
        linearLayoutSubParent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayoutSubParent.setWeightSum(100f); 

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutSubParentParams =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 90f); // you  can add multiple view, by providing weight.
        linearLayoutSubParent.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutSubParentParams);
        linearLayoutSubParent.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        final Button button = new Button(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        editTextParams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
        button.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);

        button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.list_item_Big_text_size));
        button.setText("Text");
        button.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
        button.setEnabled(false);
        linearLayoutSubParent.addView(button);
        linearLayoutParent.addView(linearLayoutSubParent);


 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutParent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
              >
</LinearLayout>
```